# Jquery to get the value on radio button click

Tags: jquery

In the radio button click i have to get the customparamvalues.For that on the `onclick` of radio button i write the following code

```
function myfunc(ele) {

    var $tr = $(ele).parent().parent();
    var name =$tr.find("td:eq(2)").html();    //alerts name its getting   
    var scripts = $tr.find("td:eq(3)").html(); //alerts scripts  its getting 

   alert("Custom Param values.........."+$tr.find("td:eq(4)").html())
// it alerts my values 1:ONE<br>2:TWO<br> 3:THREE<br>4:FOUR

}
```

so in  `$tr.find("td:eq(4)").html()` i got in the following format

```
1:ONE<br>2:TWO<br> 3:THREE<br>4:FOUR
```

What i want is  i have to output values in the following format how it is possible...

```
 var val1 = 1;
  var  val2 =ONE

var val3=2
var val4=Two
..........
.............
```

my html code

```
joblist = joblist + "<table class='tablestyle'><tr><th class='thstyle'>Select</th><th class='thstyle' id='td_1'>Id</th><th class='thstyle'>Name</th><th class='thstyle'>Test Script</th><th class='thstyle'>CustomParamValues</th></tr>";


var tabString = '<tr ><td align="center" class="tdstyle"> ' + '<input type="radio" name="joblist" onclick="myfunc(this);"  id= ' + value._id + 'value=' + value._id + '> </td><td id="td_1" align="center" class="tdstyle">' + value._id + '</td><td align="center" class="tdstyle">' + value.names + '</td><td align="center" class="tdstyle">' + value.script + '</td><td class="tdstyle">' + value.CustomParam1key + ':' + value.CustomParam1Value + '<br>' + value.CustomParam2key + ':' + value.CustomParam2Value + '<br> ' + value.CustomParam3key + ':' + value.CustomParam3Value + '<br>' + value.CustomParam4key + ":"+ value.CustomParam4Value + '</td></tr>';

                    joblist = joblist + tabString;
```

Comment: What's the issue? Seems as though you have a reference to all of your elements...so just output their values?

Comment: am getting values in this format '1:ONE<br>2:TWO<br> 3:THREE<br>4:FOUR'.i have to filter these to 'var val1 = 1;
  var  val2 =ONE'

Comment: BTW `$(ele)` in the function is redundant if you pass `$('#foo')` as the argument, as it equates to `$($(ele))`.

Comment: i didnt get anything...will u please read my question clearly

Comment: This is a mess. Paste some formatted html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering your string is alway in this format `1:ONE<br>2:TWO<br> 3:THREE<br>4:FOUR`

instead of creating a variable , you can push the text to an object or array and use that later. using `split()` to split the html(text).

for example:

```
var obj = [];
var data = $tr.find("td:eq(4)").html();
data1 = data.split('<br>');
for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
  datas2 = datas[i].split(':');
  for (var j = 0; j < datas2.length; j++) {
    obj.push(datas2[j]);
  }
}
```

here, obj will have all the values you need..

```
 alert(obj[0]) //gives 1
 alert(obj[1]) //gives ONE
 alert(obj[4]) //gives 3 ..soon
```

however, this is one of many ways to get what you want...though using two for loop is not good

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/khzC8/)